How to save a file from HTML selector to CPanel storage for VueJS
I am trying to save a file from html file input to my cloudPanel storage so i can retrieve it later if needed via html . I have tried searching for answers but they don't work, as in, the console shows no errors and succeeds, but the files are nowhere to be found.
The project is in VueJS.
The code i tried which was the most commonly resulted answer is below:
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" @change="handleImageUpload" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleImageUpload(event) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          const dataUrl = e.target.result;
          try {
            localStorage.setItem(file, dataUrl);
            console.log("Image saved to local storage. " + file);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error saving image:", error);
          }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.
P.S i'm not that good with programming and am in the learning phase.

localStorage is not cloudPanel!

Okay, understood. And the solution?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from the code you've presented it appears like you are trying to store the file on the users local machine, but from your question I suspect you are trying to store the file on your server.
Storing any data on your server through a client will require you to host a service which can do it for you. Personally I would write my own to make sure I have full control over how long I want to store the files.
If you host a service to store the files on the server you will need to make a request to that endpoint from your client. Here is one way of making such requests.
I hope this helps you :)
